# Open "Find Printer" from command line. Not "Add Printer"

Tags: windows-10, command-line, printer, command-line-arguments, run-dialog

Windows 10

Is it possible to modify this entry to open the "Find Printer" dialogue?

```
RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /ii /f %windir%\inf\ntprint.inf
```

I am able to open "Add Printer" with this but I need to open the second dialogue after you've opened "Add Printer" and select "Find a printer in the directory, based on location or feature"...... I don't see a switch for doing so.

I am on a campus of 600+ users and am trying to make this as simple as possible by adding a batch script to everyone's desktop simply called "Add Printer" that will launch the "Find Printer" dialogue. I know it's just one more click but it's one more thing someone is bound to forget how to do. A recent GPO update has trickled down the corporate ladder causing our previous way of doing things to no longer be accessible and who knows how long it'll take for them to fix it or if they'll even bother...

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the "Find a Printer in the directory" option?

If so, Open a Notepad, copy this code:

```
[CommonQuery]
Handler=5EE6238AC231D011891C00A024AB2DBBC1
Form=70F077B5E27ED011913F00AA00C16E65DB
[DsQuery]
ViewMode=0413000017
EnableFilter=0000000000
```

Save the document with any name but with a .QDS extension. I did "FindPrinter.QDS"

Double click your newly created shortcut and watch the magic happen! Try it out!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).